# Using vpasolve to find multiple solutions

Tags: octave

I'm using GNU octave and the symbolic package there to solve numerical solutions. This is one of my sample session:

```
octave> pkg load symbolic
octave> syms x
octave> vpasolve(x^2 == 1)
ans = (sym) 1.0000000000000000000000000000000
```

What I'm expecting is a solution containing the answer both `1` and `-1`. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I have been using a wrong function. Using [solve function](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/@sym/solve.html) fixes it for me:

```
octave > pkg load symbolic
octave > syms x
octave > solve(x^2 == 1, x)
```

```
: octave> ans = (sym 2×1 matrix)
: 
:   ⎡-1⎤
:   ⎢  ⎥
:   ⎣1 ⎦
```